# Как задать DataContext в разметке?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

У меня `DataContext` окна присвоен элементу `Class1`, но как задать `DataContext` элементу `Class2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

```
<Window>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:SomeViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
</Window>
```

где SomeViewModel - это какая-то модель, например, ClassX.

Хорошие примеры по теме есть в [WPF Futures](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/14962) (WPF Model-View-ViewModel Toolkit).

Comment: А что если класс имеет конструктор с параметрами ? Как тогда поступить ?